# Query of a query in SQLite / Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been modeling some queries in MS Access so they show what I want and how I want them before I translate them over to my Android app.

However, my results require two queries to get the final results -- one query to do a bunch of joins, and then a second query that joins the first query to some additional tables. If I could combine them I would but didn't see a way to.

Anyways, is there a way in SQLite that allows me to do this efficiently?

EDIT: Example:

```
Customers Table: ID, CustName
Orders Table: ID, CustID, ItemID
Items Table: ID, ItemName

Query1: SELECT Orders.ID AS OrderID, Orders.CustID, Orders.ItemID, Customers.CustName
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustID = Customers.ID;

Query2: SELECT Query1.OrderID, Query1.CustID, Query1.ItemID, Query1.CustName, Items.ItemName
FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN Items ON Query1.ItemID = Items.ID;
```

I know in this case you can easily combine these two, but let's pretend they were sufficiently complex so you had to keep them separate. I want a way to get the results of `Query2` in my Android app (which uses SQLite).

Comment: ... ever heard of `Views`?

Comment: Heard of them, but don't know what they are or how they can be used here.

Comment: Can you give an example of the queries you need? Or at least explain the table schema and what data you want from the database?

Comment: My queries are massive, so I don't know if I can relate everything here without complicating things. Maybe I can try to make some basic examples that get the idea across.

Comment: Views are indeed `"stored queries"`. But they can be accessed as if they were "virtual tables"`

Comment: @Rotwang I don't think `View`s are relevant to the question. The OP seems to be asking how to write a SQL query that has the same behavior as he sees in Access.

Comment: Yes, you should give simple examples that illustrate what you want to do. Keep it as simple as possible, but no simpler.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The OP seems to need to access virtual tables. Which is what Views actually are

Comment: @Rotwang Ahh...since the question is tagged as Android, I was thinking of a different kind of `View`.

Comment: I mean [`SQL Views`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm) ;)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added an example to the post

Comment: If a `View` is what I think it is, then I think it would work, assuming it works sort of like making the results of `Query1` a temporary table that I can then access via `Query2` like it were any other table. I am not sure if that's right though or how I'd set that up correctly.

Comment: Yes, more or less. It's actually a **query**. But you can treat it as if it was a **table**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every query, regardless how complex it is, can be used as a subquery in another query's FROM clause:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) AS Query1 JOIN ...;
```

Anyway, [CREATE VIEW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) sounds exactly like what you want:

> The CREATE VIEW command assigns a name to a pre-packaged SELECT statement. Once the view is created, it can be used in the FROM clause of another SELECT in place of a table name.

```sql
CREATE VIEW Query1 AS
SELECT Orders.ID AS OrderID,
       Orders.CustID,
       Orders.ItemID,
       Customers.CustName
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustID = Customers.ID;
```

Comment: How would I do this in the context of Java/Android/SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: By executing this statement just like you would execute any other statement.

Comment: So I would do `db.rawQuery("CREATE VIEW Query1 AS (SELECT Orders.ID AS OrderID, Orders.CustID, Orders.ItemID, Customers.CustName
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustID = Customers.ID);");` and then `db.rawQuery("SELECT Query1.OrderID, Query1.CustID, Query1.ItemID, Query1.CustName, Items.ItemName
FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN Items ON Query1.ItemID = Items.ID;");`?

Comment: The first one is not a query.

Comment: db.execSQL then, perhaps?